# Private static URL for AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, aws-vpc

I have multiple services running in the elastic beanstalk. Say service A, Service B and Service C. These 3 services should be on the same network. All these services are connected with the domain name from route 53 and pointed to the private IP respectively:

1. a.example.com --> 10.0.0.11
2. b.example.com --> 10.0.0.12
3. c.example.com --> 10.0.0.13

Now the problem is when Elastic beanstalk restarts, it creates a new machine with new private IP. So, I cannot hardcode the private IP address, Instead, I need a static private IP or a name for the Elastic Beanstalk. Also, I cannot use the public URL of the elastic beanstalk for the route 53 records because these applications need to be private.

Basic network architecture for the reference.
[image]

Any help?

Comment: got the solution?